# maximum bipartite matching (ford-fulkerson)

Tags: algorithm, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I was reading http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm and am having trouble understanding. It seems the example is under the assumptions that each job can only accept 1 person and each person wants 1 job. I was wondering how the algorithm/code would change if for example, the v set had capacity > 1 (can hire multiple people for that job) and the u set > 1 (each person wants more than 1 job)?

Comment: You just have edge capacities > 1 on the left and right side of the graph and find the maximum flow as usual. Your algorithm needs to be a bit more general to keep track of the bottleneck capacity of the augmenting path. You can read about Ford-Fulkerson [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm)

Comment: So let's say each person wants exactly 2 jobs and each job has 3 spots available. Would the graph look like this? http://i.imgur.com/B0SvQjU.png

Comment: The edges in the middle should have capacity 1, unless you want to assign a person to the same job multiple times (which might be sensible depending on your use case). Then you find the max-flow in that graph and check whether it is equal to 8 (sum of capacities on the left side). If not then you can't fulfill every need for a job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To allow jobs to have more than one person assigned to them, you'd only modify edge capacities from `Jobs` to `Terminal` (Similar to how Niklas B. described in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747088/maximum-bipartite-matching-ford-fulkerson/22779840#comment34672245_22747088), but not exactly.)

Like this:

[image: Flow network]

The capacities of 1 from the `Source` to the `People`, and 1 from `People` to `Jobs` guarantees that a person will only ever be selected for one job (because the maximum flow that they can contribute overall is 1). However, the capacities `> 1` from `Jobs` to `Terminal` allows that more than one person can be assigned to that job.

If a person can perform also more than 1 job, then the max flow from `Source` to `Person` increases by that amount:

[image: Another flow network]

Where `i`, `j`, `k`, and `x` are stand-ins for integers with values `>= 1`

The key thing to remember here is that flow capacities to the left of `People` dictate how many jobs they may take, and the flow capacities to the right of `Jobs` dictate how many people may be assigned that job. The capacities in the middle should not change.